feching error to communicate with contoller by flutter in a iot device
i am doing a project pizza vending machine . in this project a android 5.0.1 bord is connected with controller through umart (serial) port . what will be the best way to read write data command to controller with flutter
mention a librery which will the best way to read write in controller

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_libserialport

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
